# animateWithDuration stops animate

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, user-interface, animatewithduration

My code uses `animateWithDuration` in few places.

Everything works fine and the animation plays alright for a while, but - sometimes the screen suddenly freezes for half second and all the animation in all views stops play.

Means - the objects animation effected, but it ignores the duration or delay parameters.

I really guess it is up to some background processes, but I am really not sure about it.

In some places in code I use `animateWithDuration` inside methods that run under `performSelectorOnMainThread`, but it does not make a difference.

I'd be glad to hear ideas of why it happens and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you watched the debug session? Are you killing CPU/Memory? Can you post code?

Comment: Hi @JayMorgan, all animation blocks are usual animateWithDuration, and all are working fine until something that I can't explain happens. I'll check the CPU issue, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like something might be blocking your main thread. Are you using Core data fetches, or some networking operations at the time of weird behaviour ?

Comment: thanks @stringCode - well, yes. I do send web requests, but the bug can also happen after the web requests are finished. The app actually works when it happens, but the animations doesn't. Any idea? Is there any way to "free" the main thread?

Comment: Problem is you gotta figure out what it is thats blocking it ...

Comment: Did you confirm that animation blocks get called when you suspected them to and that they only get called when you expect them to. try put a break point inside of animation blocks

Comment: @stringCode - well, yes. The animation happens, but without the animation effect. The duration and delay parameters are being ignored once this issue happens.